# Large SVG animated code slows down the page

Tags: javascript, html, performance, svg, gsap

I have 2 SVG graphics that are over 600 lines of code. I'm animating them with GSAP. However, on IE and Edge it takes quite a bit to load all the html.

How to make this code load faster or minimize SVG? I know I can't have img tag cause then animations won't work. Are there other options to render SVGs?

Comment: Please be precise about what takes long. 600 lines of code isn't much, and download times are download times, regardless of the browser used. What is the file size in kilobytes, and what else is loaded by your site? Does the SVG contain raster images embeded as data urls? Filter effects? Both are known to slow down rendering, especially when in combination with animations. Is the animation choppy?

Comment: It's a bit choppy, but not on Chrome, only on IE/Edge. 
Both SVG are around 600 lines, so only svg has around 1200 lines. Page has around 700KB. Is that not much? Loading gsap, jquery, bootstrap, standard stuff. I have minified all the images. No data urls but i'm embedding images like this:
<pattern x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1"> <image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="./url" /> </pattern>

Comment: (was there something to follow after the colon?) Lines are not a good indicator of size. For typical XML content, I'd expect 600 lines to end up at about 20-30kB. What is 700KB? All loaded resources together, or the HTML page alone? Again, from typical experiences, loading of SVG content takes only a fraction of the time it takes for Javascript libraries to be parsed. Please use the developer tools to profile the loading times of your site with the performance tools and look closely what really takes long.

Comment: SVG that's 1200 lines is 150kb, so there is around 400kb in total of only SVG code and the rest is header, footer and few other static components. Thanks, I will try if there is something wrong with javascript.

Comment: It looks like the animation slightly improves when i remove the pattern image. Do you know if there is another way of filling an svg with an image?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to optimize your SVG using a tool like svg-optimizer?

You might want to take a look at this : http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-optimiser